# Complex differentiable function with non-continuous partial dervative

Tags: derivatives

I'm looking for a complex-valued function $f$ which is complex differentiable in $z_0$ but where the partial-derivatives are non-continuous in $z_0$.

Can someone give an example?

Best!
Annette

Comment: What partial derivatives? What is the domain of the function you're looking for?

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822224/is-there-any-function-that-is-differentiable-at-z-0-but-not-analytic-at-the-same?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven No, complex differentiability _in an open set_ implies smoothness.

Answer (score 1):

We can cheat and modify the standard real-variable example: $$f(z)=\begin{cases}|z|^2\sin(1/|z|),&z\ne0,
\\0,&z=0.\end{cases}$$. (To show $\partial f/\partial x$ is not continuous at the origin, note that $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x>0$.)

**Exercise** Explain what would go wrong with the proof that $f'(0)=0$ if we'd said $z^2\sin(1/z)$ instead.

**Exercise** Show that the example modified as above is *not* differentiable at the origin.